# Where did my partition go?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, mount, partitioning

Yesterday, I reinstalled Windows Vista and now I want to recover my old data from the old partition.

But the partition isn't visible. Where did it go?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use ALL-CAPITALS.

Comment: God, why do you even migrate this here? Possibly related, by the same user: [i cant see my partion in windows vista.urgt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156639/i-cant-see-my-partion-in-windows-vista-urgt) (sic)

Answer (score 1):

The partitions are still there, but they are not mounted. You need to assign a drive letter to them and they will appear in my computer.

You can do that from within Disk Management. [Here is a tutorial](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/change-drive-letters-windows-7.htm) explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a windows setup disk and when u will be asked for selecting partition for setup; just look for any unallocated space, and create a partition there. Abort the installation; restart the computer. Hope this helps.